# Circular list rotate bottom to top - Excel Formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a list of people, which could be different number of people. I would like to rotate them every year. They cannot be rotated to the same position though. E.g.,

```
Paul       Lysander
George     Paul
Lysander   George
```

Next year:

```
Paul       George
George     Lysander
Lysander   Paul
```

but never:

```
Paul       Paul
George     George
Lysander   Lysander
```

For some reason I can't even think of where to start on this. It has to be a formula and flexible as to add or take away people.

**UPDATE:**

OK, here's the "easy" part. Now I just need to figure out the hard part - no repeating:

```
Base Year: 1968
#OfPeople: =COUNTA(B:B)-1
Offset:    =YEAR(NOW())-BaseYear
New Row    =MOD(row()+Offset, #OfPeople)+2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For no-repeating, you could use the formula (in C2, see figure below):

```
=MOD(C1-1,$A$3-1)+1
```

This number (say, `Offset1`) will give you the "true" number of times you have to rotate (cycle) your list. C1 contains the order of the cycle (your `Offset`, or the "fictitious" number of rotations), and A3 contains the number of items (probably `#OfPeople+1`). `Offset1` would replace `Offset`. As `Offset` increases (=1,2,3,4,5,...), `Offset1` cycles as 1,2,3,1,2,... (if the number of items in your list is 4). So, you are effectively skipping 0 (which gives your original list).
You might need minor variations if I did not fully understand your description, but following the essence posted.

Then to compute the rotated value, you enter in C3

```
=OFFSET($B$3,MOD(ROW($B3)-ROW($B$3)-C$2,$A$3),0)
```

and copy down and to the right.

There are no array formulas and no lookup formulas. Depending on the size of your sheet, this might be faster than a lookup.

[image]

Comment: Offsetting C1 by one doesn't make it so it doesn't repeat, it just makes the repeat happen later.

Comment: @Jon49 - Offsetting C1 is not the key. Decreasing by 1 the second argument of `MOD` is. Check the figure, I think that is what you are looking for (and it was done with the formulas posted).

Comment: It looks like you got it. I'll implement it into mine just to double check. Great work. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This could get you started:

Assume your list of names is in B1:B3 and that you have the numbers 1, 2, 3 in A1:A3.

Now define a cell, say C1, with the number of years elapsed since the first year. This would be 0=first year, 1=second, 2=third, etc.

Finally, in cell D1 put the formula =VLOOKUP(MOD(A1-$C$1-1; 3)+1;$A$1:$B$3;2) and copy the formula to cells D2 and D3.

When C1=0, the formulas copy the three names. When C1=1, the names rotate by 1. When C1=2, the names rotate by one again.

Comment: Thanks, I like your use of VLOOKUP. I incorporate that into my code.